# how to check bluetooth connectivity on startup

Tags: android

I am new to android, i am developing simple app for checking bluetooth connectivity on starting main activity. below is my code. What is wrong...? I just want to check the bluetooth connectivity before anything else. Should i put that method somewhere else then onCreate() method?

```
package com.example.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.bluetooth.*;
import android.content.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public void testBT(){
    BluetoothAdapter mAdp = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    if(!mAdp.isEnabled())
    {
        Intent btIntent= new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(btIntent,1);
    }
  }
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    testBT();

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the problem? Are you experiencing null pointer exception?

If so, try adding this condition

```
if(mAdp == null){
   // this means that your device does not support bluetooth
}
```

Comment: yeah i know it. but this app is just not working on both physical device and on emulator... just a msg "Unfortunately Test<app name> has stopped"

Comment: After adding that condition it works fine with emulator(Assuming that emulator dosnt have Bluetooth)... but still its not working on physical device.

Comment: oops.. i forgot to setup Bluetooth permissions in AndroidManifest.xml. Now its working. :)

Comment: 1. Have you added android.permission.BLUETOOTH to your manifest?
2. Does your app throw any errors on your physical device? What does the full stack trace say?

Comment: 50 seconds late xD Congrats.